# passing pointers to a function

Tags: c

This is the prototype of my function

```
void classifier_rules(struct classifier *k, struct classifier *ptr_keys);
```

This is how I have assigned address of a pointer

```
struct classifier keys,*ptr_keys;
ptr_keys = &keys;
```

I have called this function classifier_rules in another function like this

```
classifier_rules(&(ptr->keys[pos]), &ptr_keys); 
here i get a error  ‘ptr_keys’ undeclared (first use in this function)

classifier_rules(struct classifier *rules, struct classifier ptr_keys )
{
 this is the body of function;

}
```

hHw to remove this error, I want the address of keys to be passed failing to do so I may access some wrong memory location

Comment: Can you post the body of the calling function? Also, your function definition doesn't match the prototype - is that just a typo?

Comment: ptr_keys is a parameter of classifier_rules ... how can you expect it to be defined in another function? That suggests very serious and basic misunderstandings about the language. You should consider starting with simpler programming problems until you have mastered the basics.

Comment: Take a look at this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_scope

Comment: You should definitely read more about pointers. This is good [place to start](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
struct classifier keys,*ptr_keys
```

is in your calling function, then it should work. (Or at least you should get a different error).

You shouldn't be passing &ptr_keys.

```
classifier_rules(&(ptr->keys[pos]), ptr_keys); 
//ptr_keys is already a pointer, you don't need to use a '&'
```